# html loader in webpack configuration js file not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
webpack.config.js

 module.exports = {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.html$/i,
            loader: "html-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
    };

            this is my route component in react 

            import htmlContent from './Vanilla-quiz-app-js/index.html';

            const RouteProject = () => {
                return (
                    <Routes>
                            <Route path='/' element={App} />
                            <Route path='calculator' element={<Appcalculator />}/>
                            <Route path='quiz' element={<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlContent}}/>} />
                            <Route path='card' element={<Appcard />}/>
                    </Routes>
                )
            }

     my-app/
      ├─ node_modules/
      ├─ public/
      │   ├─ favicon.ico
      │   ├─ index.html
      │   ├─ robots.txt
      ├─ src/
      │  ├─ App.js
      │  ├─ calculator_project/
      │  ├─ cardMemory_project/
      │  ├─ vanilla-quiz-app_project/
      │  ├─ routes/
      │  │  ├─ routeProject
      │  ├─ App.css
      │  ├─ index.js
      ├─ .gitignore
      ├─ package.json
      ├─ README.md **
```

----------- the problem -------------

- i have a js project and i wanna use it in react component, so i should import index.html
  from js project.

i set a html loader in webpack configuration js file but not working

Comment: could you please provide folder structure of your project?

Comment: it's provided .

Comment: each project has its own webpack config ?

Comment: yes, but vanilla js doesn't